# Limit on number of simultaneous connection to gmail server from a single server

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I was wondering if gmail(Google mail in general) has any limits for number of simultaneous connections that can be open from a single server for different accounts?

The use case is that, I'm trying to write a email engine from backend. I would like to connect to different email accounts from a single server.

I tried to look around on web for this, but couldn't find anything related to this. All I found was the limit on number of connections that can be open for an account(which is 15).

Anybody have any idea on the limit for number of connections that can be open from a server? Is there any such limit at all?

Comment: are you using the Gmail API or going directly in via the SMTP / IMAP servers?

Comment: Directly to IMAP. Not using Gmail API

Comment: I suspect you may actually get blocked doing this if it's in the hundreds of accounts.

Comment: The limit is 64k connections to a single IP/port (you need a TCP port number per connection and those are 16-bit), but Google will notice it and perhaps scowl well before you exhaust that. If you exhaust the 64k limit you can add more IP addresses on your end... but if you have to ask, you may as well pretend the limit is 64k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of connections allowed to an IMAP server directly is going to be in the billions. I don't think that Google is going to do any checking to see if your server is sending to many.

The fifteen limit per account kind of makes scene.   However you need to consider how many email systems run on servers these days.  Its going to be normal that a lot of incoming request come from the same server however are directed to different accounts.

This is just my opinion i don't think your going to find any documentation on Googles side telling you that you can spam there server as much as you want.